# Showing path in file-tabs in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've got a component-based folder structure in my project. It is a bunch of component-folders with one `index.js` file each.

Is it possible to make Visual Studio Code display the parent folder name in the file tabs? Or am I limited to seeing a bunch of tabs that all display `index.js` and nothing else?

[image]

Comment: There is a thread about it here
[https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8499](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8499)

Comment: This setting will show the full path in the title bar (though not the tab): `“window.title”: “${activeEditorLong}${separator}${rootName}”`

Comment: `${activeEditorMedium}${separator}${rootName}` works even better imo, I don't see a reason to see the entire path of the file as opposed to path from src root

Answer (score 284, accepted):

You can configure Visual Studio Code to **always** show parent folder names in the tabs! In your *User Settings*, just add this line: `"workbench.editor.labelFormat": "short"` (other values are "long", "medium" or "default")

Result: the files `init/views.js`, `init/routes.js` and `plugins/modal.js` will be presented as such:

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio Code file tabs]

---

Another option is the User Setting `"breadcrumbs.enabled": true` which for shows a row of breadcrumbs with the complete file path - in the Code view below the Active tab.

[image: Screenshot of breadcrumbs]

---

**PS:** To open User Settings use the File-menu → *Preferences* → *Settings* → *User Settings*. To view the settings in a JSON format just click the `{}` icon in the top right corner.

Answer (score 30):

Go to the main menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings*. And search for (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> on Mac; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> on Windows and Linux) *workbench label format*.

Choose the *short* option.

Comment: There are two *"Label Format"* in the search result: *"Workbench ► Editor: Label Format"* and *"Workbench ► Editor ► Untitled: Label Format"*

Comment: For version 1.45 (2020-04).

Comment: The second has different options, *"Content"* and *"Name"*

Comment: Perhaps use a search term that will result in a single hit (currently there are 10 hits)?

Comment: Enclosing in quotes cuts the number of hits down from 34 to 7 (version 1.45.1, 2020-05-14): `"workbench label format"`

Comment: The search can be made unique (only one search hit) by typing out (or pasting) the setting ID: `workbench.editor.labelFormat`

Comment: Yes, using *"short"* will display the parent folder (this question). To display absolute paths, use *"long"*.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is too late to answer, but in case someone is looking for the `file path` to show on the `title bar`, you can follow this:

1. Open settings (`command` + `,`)
2. Search for `title`
3. You'll see something like `activeEditorShort`, replace it with `activeEditorLong`
4. Save

**Source**:
https://medium.com/riow/vscode-show-full-path-in-title-bar-b0cb731b330

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio Code has now improved their tab-UI to resolve this issue.

When you've opened multiple tabs with the same filename, Visual Studio Code will automatically display the parent foldername in each of those tabs.

Here's an example: I've opened two `index.js` files and one `event.js` file. VsCode decides it's a good idea to display the foldername for the `index.js` files but not for the `event.js` file since that filename is unique

[image]

This is enough for me in some situations (when I've got lots of files with the same name)

Comment: There is also a setting to control the behavior and format of the label:

 "workbench.editor.labelFormat"

Answer (score 4):

Step 1: Go to File > Preferences > Settings

Step 2: search for "workbench.editor.labelFormat"

Step 3: select **medium** from a drop-down

Answer (score 2):

[Video reference codeGrepper](https://youtu.be/KnMJQQEjOZI)

Go to vs code setting and search "Label format"
you will see

> Workbench › Editor: Label Format
> Controls the format of the label for an editor.

change from default to **short.**

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [nice-index](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stekoshy.nice-index&ssr=false#overview) extension for a better experience dealing with index files.

However, as of now, it only works when you have more than one index file open. This can be resolved by changing labelFormat to "short", as other answers suggest.

Comment: The link leads to a `404` error page.

Comment: Seems like the plugin was discontinued. I stopped using it months ago and rather stopped using index files at all, it was a nightmare to keep an overview of which tab is which file.

Answer (score -1):

In VSCode 1.53 you can use thees settings:

Controls the window title based on the active editor. Variables are substituted based on the context:

```
${activeEditorShort}: the file name (e.g. myFile.txt).
${activeEditorMedium}: the path of the file relative to the workspace folder (e.g. myFolder/myFileFolder/myFile.txt).
${activeEditorLong}: the full path of the file (e.g. /Users/Development/myFolder/myFileFolder/myFile.txt).
${activeFolderShort}: the name of the folder the file is contained in (e.g. myFileFolder).
${activeFolderMedium}: the path of the folder the file is contained in, relative to the workspace folder (e.g. myFolder/myFileFolder).
${activeFolderLong}: the full path of the folder the file is contained in (e.g. /Users/Development/myFolder/myFileFolder).
${folderName}: name of the workspace folder the file is contained in (e.g. myFolder).
${folderPath}: file path of the workspace folder the file is contained in (e.g. /Users/Development/myFolder).
${rootName}: name of the opened workspace or folder (e.g. myFolder or myWorkspace).
${rootPath}: file path of the opened workspace or folder (e.g. /Users/Development/myWorkspace).
${appName}: e.g. VS Code.
${remoteName}: e.g. SSH
${dirty}: a dirty indicator if the active editor is dirty.
${separator}: a conditional separator (" - ") that only shows when surrounded by variables with values or static text.
```

Comment: While this is useful, it's unrelated to the question, which is about setting the titles of the editor tabs.