# Show more path in vscode tabs

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to show more of the dir path in the tab name?

e.g.

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39598007/showing-path-in-file-tabs-in-visual-studio-code/50181247#50181247 and the default `workbench.editor.tabSizing` set to `fit`.

Comment: Thanks alot, sorry for the some what duplicate post.